# Polygons not showing in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, polygon-creation

I am using ArcGIS 10.2. I have used the following procedure to creat polygon:

1. 'Add XY data' to create points
2. 'XY to line' to create line (but I could not see the lines)
3. 'feature to polygon' to create polygons (but could not see the polygons)

Can anyone assist me what I should do to see the polygons?

Here are examples of my points: (25,12.5), (-17.540,-10), (-17.54,10), (42.5,-12.5), (51.403,-34.791), (51.403,-10).

Comment: Please give an example of your XY data.

Comment: Can you see at least the points? :)

Comment: Did you have attributes in your line attribute table?

Comment: Note that you may need to export the points to a shapefile or feature class after you create them (XY data only creates a temporary layer) in order to run a GP tool on them. I'm assuming that after each tool ran you choose to add the results to the map. If you can't see anything, is the attribute table empty? If so, nothing was created.

Comment: Mappet, alex, dof1985 and Chris, thank you so much for your responses and cooments. Iam able to see the points, but not able to see the lines and polygons. In line attribute table, I have attributes. In polygon attribute table, I only have one item (indicating that something is very wrong). I will try the suggestion you (Chris) have provided.

Comment: here is an example of my points:

Comment: Here is an example of my points:(25,12.5), (-17.540,-10), (-17.54,10), (42.5,-12.5), (51.403,-34.791), (51.403,-10)

Comment: You might be able to skip the first step. The XY to Line tool can take a csv as input. However, what settings are you using in that tool? Specifically, how does it know what points to connect with a line? A screenshot of your points would help, as would one of the tool settings for XY to Line. I'm wondering I the lines even close regions for polygons (though I understand you can't see them, so...). Please use the **edit** button at the lower left corner of your question under the tags to add additional information, rather than just posting it in comments.

Comment: Is it possible to zoom to the layer, using the `zoom to layer` option?

Is the spatial reference set correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Yes **XY To Line** tool shows some error sometimes without any reason (for my case it showed arcpy module import error!!!)

If nothings work to generate **polygon**, then i would use build convex hull based on the unique identifier (ID field in picture) as below.

[image: convex]

**N.B. It generates separate polygon based on unique value**